# how is _Bool implemented?

Tags: c

What is it that makes value in a variable of type _Bool 1 , even when we assign a value greater than 1 to it.

For ex:

```
_Bool tmp = 10;

printf("%x , %lu", tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

This would print 1, 1. Trying to understand what is it that makes a variable of size Byte act as a single bit and when assigned a value > 1 which has LSB 0 still get converted to 1.

Comment: It is *Implementation Defined* other than 4-required macros [C11 Standard - 7.18 Boolean type and values <stdbool.h>](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.18)

Comment: A little unrelated nitpicking: The correct format to print a `size_t` (the result of the `sizeof` operator) is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: An implementation does whatever is necessary to behave as the standard prescribes. If you are interested in a particular compiler, look at the assembly it generates.

Comment: The compiler's job is to implement the rules of the language  . Is your question about compiler construction or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is it that makes value in a variable of type _Bool 1 , even when we assign a value greater than 1 to it.* The compiler does.

For example on ARM (arm-none-eabi-gcc):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdbool.h"

int main()
{

_Bool tmp = 10;

printf("%x , %lu", tmp, sizeof(tmp));


return 0;

}
```

compiles to:

```
.LC0:
        .ascii  "%x , %lu\000"
main:
        stmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
        add     fp, sp, #4
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        mov     r3, #1
        strb    r3, [fp, #-5]
        ldrb    r3, [fp, #-5]   @ zero_extendqisi2
        mov     r2, #1
        mov     r1, r3
        ldr     r0, .L3
        bl      printf
        mov     r3, #0
        mov     r0, r3
        sub     sp, fp, #4
        ldmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   .LC0
```

you can see in the instruction `mov     r3, #1` that the compiler directly converts the initialisation value `10` to `1` as specified by the standard .